# Replacement String for course section?

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a replacement string I can use to target a specific section within a course?  I know that I can use `{OrgUnitName}` as a replacement string for the course name, but is there a replacement string I can use for specific sections within a course?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any course section tokens as of version 10. These are the ones that seem to be available:

- orgunitid
- orgunittypeid
- orgunitpath
- orgunitname
- orgunitcode
- orgid
- orgname
- userid
- username
- firstname
- lastname
- orgdefinedid
- email
- internalemail
- externalemail
- roleid
- rolecode
- rolename