# Why don't replacement strings work as they should in Desire2Learn content?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'd like to know why replacement strings work properly in Desire2Learn widgets, but not in the Desire2Learn Content tool.  And are there any plans to fix them there?  It is really causing a lot of trouble for us that they don't work the way we thought they did when we were deciding to purchase Desire2Learn.

This post explains the behavior of replacement strings in content.
[Desire2Learn Replace Strings in Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772647/desire2learn-replace-strings-in-content)

This would be so much more useful if you could actually use it in course content.  As it is, it isn't very useful.
[Replacement String for course section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800371/replacement-string-for-course-section)